# How to create cart by customer magento2

Tags: magento2, cart

I need to create empty cart if the customer doesn't have an existing cart.

The code below works fine if the cart exists, and if it does not exist, it displays an error

`No such entity with customerId = 161 No such entity with customerId = 162`

```
...

$data = [
         'qty' => $products_count,
         'product' => $products_id,
          'bundle_option' => $selectionProds
          ];

 $request->setData($data);


$quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->getForCustomer($customer_id);
$quote->addProduct($_product, $request);

$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                               $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
$quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
$quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
$quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

$this->_quoteRepository->save($quote);
$quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
$quote->collectTotals();
$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
$order->setEmailSent(0);
$increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
if ($order->getEntityId()) {
    $result['order_id'] = $order->getRealOrderId();
} else {
    $result = ['error' => 1, 'msg' => 'Your custom message'];
}
 return $result;
```

Comment: you can debug it, just put die('showing'); check it with line and find out in which line of code having issue and you will get the cause of issue.
I have doubt in this line : $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->getForCustomer($customer_id);
you need to add some condition line count > 1;

Comment: Saphal Jha, I know from which line the error is, $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->getForCustomer($customer_id);

Comment: you should add a condition like if customer have any product in cart then run next line of code.

Comment: Saphal Jha, thanks for answer, but it doesn't solve my problem, I need it to work and then when there are no products on the cart, then I will solve this problem if I can create it quote  before this line, this my problem :)

Comment: I don’t know if I could properly describe what I need, but one thing I know for sure is that this line doesn’t work because quote doesn't exist. Are there options that I could create empty quote for a particular customer if it doesn't exist ?

Comment: Simplest way is add a temp product in cart then get cart id then remove that product, so session will be created and you can add other products in cart

Comment: $customer->loadByEmail($getEmailCustomers);
                                   if(!$checkCartExist['entity_id']) {
                                       $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
                                       $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote

                                   }else{
                                       $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->getForCustomer($custoemrId);
                                   }

Comment: i using this way and it works for me very good